# Why will Firefox resolve my domain but Chrome will not

Tags: domain-name-system, local-area-network, internal-dns, domain-name, ipv4

I've been setting up a LAN DNS server using DNSMasq to forward my webserver which at the moment has https and is port-forwarded by my router. I have a domain registered which resolves fine from outside my LAN and I've been addressing a NAT loopback issue for requests originating in the LAN. with enough time spent pulling my hair out after exausting `ifconfig` and `dig` I opened firefox Nightly (98) to find that my domain name in the address bar resolves a https request just fine, and now somewhat relieved, I don't know why this is happening.

dig mydomain.local seems to work correctly with an A record returned for a private IP where my server is at:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> mydomain.local
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 6363
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mydomain.local.                 IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
mydomain.local.          0       IN      A       192.168.0.29

;; Query time: 3 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.0.29#53(192.168.0.29)
;; WHEN: Sun Jan 16 22:33:18 AST 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 58
```

and the IP does resolve and serve the contents of the website as expected

I've been doing some basic configuration of dnsmasq here are the basic config options I have in the `dnsmasq.conf`

```
domain-needed
bogus-priv
no-resolv
server=8.8.8.8
server=8.8.4.4
local=/localnet/
address=/mydomain.local/192.168.0.29
domain=localnet
```

and the host file contains

```
192.168.0.29    mydomain.local
```

I've cleared Chromes local dns cache at `chrome://net-internals/#dns` but nothing changed so at this moment I am wondering how chrome is different from firefox in this regard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome not only needs a dns cache flush which can be done on `Chrome: chrome://net-internals/#dns`, it also needed a flush of socket pools. So going to `chrome://net-internals/#sockets` and clicking `flush socket pools` fixed this caching issue.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome has its own DNS cache that is separate from other browsers. This would explain why other browsers don't have issues. If you want to clear DNS cache and have it affect, Chrome, go to the following page in Chrome:  chrome://net-internals/#dns

Click the "Clear host cache" button.

Comment: Thankyou for the response, I forgot to mention that I had cleared the local dns records from chrome and that made no difference.

Comment: I found that I also had to clear socket cache as well which fixed my problem! chrome://net-internals/#sockets thanks for getting me to look again.